Custom Conditional Formatting Rule Isn't Valid
I have a list of dates on one sheet, a range named "CalDates" that are as follows:
8/19/2023
8/26/2023
9/2/2023
9/16/2023
9/23/2023
I then have a calendar on another page with numbers for each of the days (see picture). Each day is functionally calculated, meaning each cell with a number is the result of an underlying formula. A custom conditional formatting formula is to be set on each day, dictating whether the day should be green or not. If the day, combined with the Year and the Month number (via the MONTH function) is in the list of CalDates, it should turn green. If not: nothing.
The formula was this (as seen in the focused cell at the top of the picture):
=IFERROR(MATCH(DATEVALUE(JOIN("/",{MATCH($I$22,Months,0),I24,$E$2})),CalDates,0)>0,False)

I put this formula into the conditional formatting area for the month of August, since one of the dates is 8/19/2023, and I wanted to test it.
The formula, when setting "I24" to "O26" registers as "TRUE", and the TRUE/FALSE grid in the picture shows the related results when applied to the relative addresses for the month of August. The formula works as expected, but it doesn't register as a valid formula in the Conditional format rules area.
I've tried several formulas of varying complexity, each one adding more and more functions used within this formula, all of them passing the validity test of the conditional formatting rule area. Yet this one doesn't work.
What's wrong with the formula?


Formulas can only reference the same sheet, using standard notation "(='sheetname'!cell)." To reference another sheet in the formula, use the INDIRECT function. This also applies to named ranges.

Thank you, @TheMaster. That's what I needed.
